# invalid identifier when executing select in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, sqlplus

I am trying to execute a select in oracle that uses 3 tables, nba_player, nba_team, and nba_team_roster.  nba_player includes player data with a player_id and nba_team includes team information with a team_id.  nba_team_roster is an associative entity and includes a player_id and team_id to associate the two. I want this query to return the first and last name of each player on team 'OKC' but for some reason it gives me the error below.  I am not sure why this isn't executing properly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
select nba_player.first_name, nba_player.last_name
from nba_player,nba_team
join nba_team_roster
on nba_team_roster.player_id=nba_player.player_id
where nba_team_roster.team_id= nba_team.team_id
and nba_team.team_name='OKC';


on nba_player.player_id=nba_team_roster.player_id
   *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: "NBA_PLAYER"."PLAYER_ID": invalid identifier

CREATE TABLE NBA_Team(
team_id number primary key,
team_name varchar(5)
);

CREATE TABLE NBA_Player(
player_id number primary key,
first_name varchar(10),
last_name varchar (11),
position varchar(3),
salary number,
points_per_game number
);

CREATE TABLE NBA_Team_Roster(
roster_ID number primary key,
team_id number,
player_id number unique,
foreign key (team_id) references NBA_Team(team_id),
foreign key (player_id) references NBA_Player(player_id)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  That will solve your problem and make the query easier to understand:

```
select p.first_name, p.last_name
from nba_player p join
     nba_team_roster r
     on r.player_id = p.player_id join
     nba_team t
     on r.team_id = t.team_id
where t.team_name = 'OKC';
```

Note that I also introduced table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar . . . Commas "work".  You just shouldn't use them.  They are out-of-date.  Think rotary-dial telephones, or crank-start automobiles, or kerosene lamps to read by.